# Are those statements Tautology?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> a.$$\forall x\forall y \exists z (x\neq y)\rightarrow (x\neq z)$$
>   b. $$\neg\exists x\forall y \forall z (x=y)\rightarrow (x=z)$$

To revoke a. we need to find a case of $(x\neq z)\land (x=y)$ and for some $x,y$ (x=y) is false, therefore $(x\neq y)\land (x=z)$ is false and it always true.

b. is $\forall x\exists y \exists z (x\neq z)\lor (x=y)$ and it is always true, because for all $x$ there $y$ such $x=y$

Comment: (b) is not true in a structure with only one element. You unfolded the negation wrongly; it should end up as $$ \forall x\exists y\exists z(x=y\land x\ne z) $$

Comment: @HenningMakholm so b. is a tautology because for all x we can find y and z such that the above is true? or because for all x we can find y and z such that the above is false, so it is not a tautology?

Comment: x @gbox: None of the above. (b) is not logically valid because _we can find a structure_ (namely the one with one element), where we can find an $x$ (namely the single element of the structure) where we _cannot_ find $y$ and $z$ such that $x=y$ and $x\ne z$.

Comment: (b) is equivalent to $$\forall \langle x,~ \exists \langle y,~ x = y \rangle \land \exists \langle z ,~ x \ne z \rangle ~ \rangle$$

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, I typed it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

a) This seems a tautology. Just take $z=y$.

b) I think you have mistaken in negating the implication.

Answer (score -2):

One has to be careful with the possible domains for formulae like this.  For (a): If the domain has two or more distinct elements x, y, then as already posted one can take z=y.  If the domain has only one element, then (a) is still true, but now it is true vacuously because the condition (x $\neq$ y) can never be satisfied.  If the domain is empty, however, then $\exists$z is always false regardless of the expression that follows.  Conclusion: NOT A TAUTOLOGY.  *[I leave (b) for the student]*

Comment: If the domain is empty in (a) then (a) is trivially a tautology because the $\forall$ evaluates to $\top$.  It is also quite rude to say "I leave (b) for the student" even if it is meant as a joke, so I have to downvote for that.